# EV charger connector identification

Tags: identification, charger, charging, electric-vehicle

I am building a portable EV charger demo for conferences, and for transportability reasons, I need the charger cable to be removable. Have you ever seen that connector?

[image]

Comment: 1. Which connector? 2. Recommendations for places to purchase things are off topic here.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide context. Where did you find that connector or photo? What is the scale of it? (Photograph it with a ruler in view.) Is there a brand identification or part number on the shell? There doesn't seem to be an metal contact material in the three large holes. Why not? I removed the shopping portion of your question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing here: power-sonic.com/blog/ev-charging-connector-types, that doesn't look even remotely like a standard EV DC Charging connector. Where did you find it?

Comment: This is some manner of Harting connector, either from the manufacturer with that name (Han series) or by someone else. Check out the Han-modular series for example, for a lot of custom stuff like this.